# Draw multivariate Gaussian distribution samples using Python numpy.random.randn

Tags: numpy, random, gaussian

I'm studying about Gaussian Mixture Model and came across this code which draws a number of samples from 2 bivariate Gaussian distributions. Which I don't understand is the technique that is used in the code:

```
import numpy as np

# Number of samples per component
n_samples = 500

# Generate random sample, two components
np.random.seed(0)
C = np.array([[0., -0.1], [1.7, .4]])
X = np.r_[np.dot(np.random.randn(n_samples, 2), C),
          .7 * np.random.randn(n_samples, 2) + np.array([-6, 3])]
```

(Original link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_selection.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-mixture-plot-gmm-selection-py)

According to [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution), we can generate multivariate Gaussian samples by Cholesky-decomposing the covariance matrix, then multiply it with a vector composed of components drawn from standard-normal distribution.

My question is the C variable in the code is not a lower triangle matrix, so how does it make sense in the multivariate Gaussian random generation?

Comment: Not an answer, but just FYI: NumPy has [`numpy.random.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html) for generating samples from the multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you. Yes, I know about `numpy.random.multivariate_normal`. What I want here is to understand the theory behind the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`X` is a mixture of two bivariate normal distributions.  Half the samples are computed with `np.dot(np.random.randn(n_samples, 2), C)`, where `C = np.array([[0., -0.1], [1.7, .4]])`.  This distribution is equivalent to a distribution whose covariance is `C.T.dot(C)`.  That is, you could generate a sample from the same distribution by using `np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], C.T.dot(C), n_samples)`.

See these notes that I wrote some time ago: ["Correlated Random Samples"](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CorrelatedRandomSamples.html). (In those notes, the 3x3 matrix `C` is multiplied on the right by a sample with shape `(3, num_samples)`.  In other words, those notes use a transpose of the formula used here, so there the covariance matrix is `C.dot(C.T)`.)   `C` doesn't have to be lower triangular.  But commonly, you are given a covariance matrix, and you want to find `C`.  If you use the Cholesky decomposition to find `C`, then by construction it will be lower triangular.

This ipython session demonstrates that the two methods generate samples from the same distribution:

```
In [60]: C = np.array([[0., -0.1], [1.7, .4]])

In [61]: X1 = np.dot(np.random.randn(n_samples, 2), C)

In [62]: X2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], C.T.dot(C), n_samples)

In [63]: plot(X1[:,0], X1[:,1], 'g*', alpha=0.2)
Out[63]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x113c17550>]

In [64]: plot(X2[:,0], X2[:,1], 'ko', alpha=0.2, ms=4)
Out[64]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x113c3ba58>]
```

[image: plot]